# Programmatically set TabLayout items titles

Tags: android, view, menuitem, android-tablayout

[image]

I need to make this type of views so I thought a TabLayout with fragments would help.

But the problem is, instead of having each menu item hardcoded, I need to make the tab titles programmatically as name may change or the amount of itemmenu also change.

I think an ArrayList of Strings can help storing each item menu title.

How can I have the titles set programmatically?

Comment: Maybe this post would to help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252193/how-to-create-tablayout-with-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Maybe this post would to help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252698/10931055

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this example:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = ...;
 /*tabItems is an Arraylist<String> with the tab names*/
 for( String tabItem: tabitems){
   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(tabItem));
 }
```

this is the official doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout

Comment: using a foreach on the arraylist and inside the settext function send the name of the tabitem